# "May (might,can) could have" and "Must should have/should must have" impossible?

Tags: modal-verbs, auxiliary-verbs

My colleague and I were discussing **Auxiliary Verbs and Modal Verbs** when we came to a point where we started experimenting and we came to "**May (might,can) could have**" and "**Must should have**" whereupon we started arguing whether they are possible or not in English. While I'm saying they are, he states they are not. I would really like a native speaker's answer on this!

He's somewhat pointing to that two auxiliary verbs and modal verbs can't stand together. I doubt though that "**can could (might, may) have**" and "**should must have**" are possible so far.

For instance:

- If it weren't for the rain, the fire **may (might) could have** spread further.
- I **could might (may) have** *(or might (may) could have)* seen this movie, still I can't say for sure.
- She couldn't look straight into his eyes after all those lies. She **must should have** told him the truth. - *I think even "**must need have told him**" or "**should need to have told him**" are possible.*

So can we or can we not place two modal verbs or (and) auxiliary verbs together?

Comment: You can add "must have had to", too :-)

Comment: @Cardinal Are you joking? It's like "**she had to do it**" plus "**she must have done it**" equals "**she must have had to do it**"?

Comment: No' I am not; it's a technique (!) to express your conclusion about an issue occurred in the past (recently happened). However, since I rarely use this structure I am not a expert on this. Maybe we should ask a new question!

Comment: **might could** is a southernism in AmE and I heard a politician from the South use **may could** on the radio a month or two ago. None of my friends from the South had ever said **may could**.  I've never heard or read modal combinations with **must** (except for the archaic **must needs**).

Comment: **must have had to** is a surmise. *She must have had to leave the office, otherwise she'd be answering her phone.*

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo *Must needs* doesn't use two modals--*needs* is the noun *need* with an archaic adverbial affix *-s*. The same construction is used in *He works nights and sleeps days*.

Comment: @StoneyB: yes, "necessarily".  I invoke the "still on my first cup of coffee" defense.

Comment: Double modals like "can could have", "should must have", "must need have" are certainly not British English. But in "should need to have told him" the "to" is part of the infinitive of the verb "have". "He must need sleep" (sleep = noun) and "He must need to sleep" (to sleep = infinitive of verb) are both OK, but "He must need have sleep" is nonsense in BrEng.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

English auxiliary verbs combine into more complex constructions according to wholly inflexible rules: the sequence is always

- the modal component first (if it is present), with the following verb in its infinitive form
- the perfect component next (if it is present), using the auxiliary *HAVE*, with the following verb in its past participle form
- the progressive component next (if it is present), using the auxiliary *BE*, with the following verb in its present participle form
- the passive component next (if it is present), using the auxiliary *BE*, with the following verb in its past participle form
- the lexical verb is always the last.

Each construction is thus marked with a specific auxiliary verb, *HAVE* or *BE*, and there is a ‘ripple’ effect: the form (present or past participle or infinitive) of each verb is determined by the preceding component.

[image: Pcon4]
Note that the English 'modal' verbs *can/could, may/might, must, shall/should, will/would* are defective: they occur only in finite forms and have no non-finite forms (infinitives and participles).

Since a modal verb cannot be cast in the appropriate non-finite form, it cannot act as complement of a prior modal verb or auxiliary: except when two modals are conjoined (*You **can and should** tell him*), you can have only one modal verb in a clause, and it must be the finite first verb.

You occasionally hear paired modals in dialect speech, but this is emphatically non-standard and is generally taken to mark the speaker as uneducated.

The work-around for situations which call for "dual modalities" is to employ a periphrasis for the second modal:

> *You might could do it → <sup>ok</sup>You might **be able** to do it.

A periphrasis like *be able to VERB* or *need to VERB* or *be obliged to VERB* in effect "restarts" the verb chain: a complex construction with its first element cast in the 'infinitive' may follow the *to*:

> If you had planned better you might have been able to ***have been working*** offsite when he arrived.

In this case, however, the first element in the new chain cannot be a modal, because modals cannot be cast in the infinitive.

Comment: As always, a much more comprehensive answer than mine ;)

Comment: Can't quite understand, so "**could may have**" and "**may could have**" are impossible?

Comment: @SovereignSun Exactly. In fact, these are beyond the pale even in dialect.

Comment: What about "**He could may have helped her but he didn't**" or "**She may could have said that but I didn't hear it**"?

Comment: @SovereignSun No. **One** modal only.

Comment: @SovereignSun If you change _may_ to _maybe_ then it would be ok.

Comment: "**may (might) could have**"  somehow still sounds okay to me.

Comment: @SovereignSun There's no problem with the *have*. *Might could have* will be heard in the vernacular, but is not accepted in standard speech or writing. I have never heard *may could* in any register or dialect.

Answer (score 2):

You can of course link an auxiliary and a modal auxiliary verb together in a sentence:

> I could be sleeping instead.
>
> You might have died!

And you can link the two auxiliary verbs *have* and *be* to form a perfect progressive tense (again, with a modal auxiliary if you want):

> I could have been eating instead.

However, I can't think of any situations where two *modal auxiliaries* together would make sense, so I assume that this would be grammatically incorrect usage. If you want to emphasise an uncertainty you can use an adverb such as *maybe*, *perhaps* or *possibly*; if you wish to emphasise an imperative you can use an adverb such as *absolutely* or *certainly*.

> I could possibly meet him.

Comment: Your last sentence feels rather unidiomatic to me.  I (BrE speaker, 50's) would say "I could perhaps meet him" (rather formal) or "I could possibly meet him" or "Perhaps/Maybe I could meet him" (rather more positive).

Comment: @MartinBonner You're right, it is probably the least common option, I'll change it.

Comment: @MartinBonner *Maybe* there is quite common in US speech. It loses any informality in other positions: *Maybe I could meet him* or *I could meet him, maybe*.

Comment: It's not that a chain of modal auxiliaries would not _make sense_ -- they are merely not _grammatical_ in (standard) English. Several other Germanic languages (whose modal auxiliaries do have infinitive forms) allow such chains without trouble, e.g. Danish "Man **skal** **kunne** læse" or German "Man **muss** lesen **können**" for "one must be-able-to read".